# Picklist values arenot setting Properly in child component side

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to query the Picklist values and I need to show at the time of page load.In my case picklist values are passing from parent to child component.But itsnot setting properly(it shows different value)

For example:

***Problem Facing***:

***In this Image:***

***For carrier "Progressive,NBIC,NBIC" value has to set.But it setted different values.***  [image]

***Parent Component:***

```
   <aura:attribute name="ComparisonQuotes" type="Object[]" />
   <aura:attribute name="Carrier" type="Object[]"/>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.ComparisonQuotes}" var="Compar">
     <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider"></h3>
  <c:Clone_S360_ComparisonQuote_Display displayComparison="{!Compar}" 
     Carrier="{!v.Carrier}" />
     </aura:iteration>
```

---

Javascript methods:

```
    helper.ComparisonQuotes(component,event,helper);
    helper.fetchCarrier(component,event,helper);
```

---

Helper:

```
    ({
     ComparisonQuotes : function(component,event,helper) {

    var OppId=component.get("v.recordId");
    var action = component.get("c.GetComparison");   
     action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state=response.getState();
        if (state =='SUCCESS') {

             component.set("v.ComparisonQuotes",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },
    fetchCarrier:function(component,event,helper) {
    var opts=[];
    var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");
    action.setParams({
        objObject:'Comparison_Quote__c',
        fld:'Carrier__c'
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state=response.getState();
          if(state=='SUCCESS'){
            for(var i=0;i<response.getReturnValue().length;i++){                                       
                opts.push({ value:response.getReturnValue()[i], label: 
    response.getReturnValue()[i]});              
            }
            component.set('v.Carrier', opts);    
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
   }  })
```

***Apex controller:***

```
//describe method
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getPicklistValues(String objObject,string fld){
     Map<string,String> mapReturn = new Map<string,String>();
      Schema.SObjectType targetType = 
         Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objObject);
    Sobject Object_name  = targetType.newSObject();
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab 
     the sobject that was passed
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldmap = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();
  List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldNames = new List<Schema.SObjectField>(); 
    // for (String fld : fieldMap.keySet()){
    list<string> options=new List<string>();
    List <string> options1 = new List<string>();
    Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getType();
    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist ||fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist) {
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = fieldMap.get(fld).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); 
        String str = String.valueOf(fieldMap.get(fld));
        String values='';
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { 
            values = values + a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel()+',';
            options1.add(a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel());  //It contains value and name label
            options.add(a.getLabel());//Here added only Label to the List
        }

        values = values.subString(0,values.length()-1);

        //mapReturn.put(str,options1);
        mapReturn.put(str,values);

    }
    // }
    System.debug('mapReturn'+mapReturn);
    return options;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Comparison_Quote__c >GetComparison(){
    system.debug('calling##');
    return [select id,Business_Type__c, Carrier__c, LOB__c,Selected__c,Sold_Premium__c from Comparison_Quote__c ];
}}
```

***child(Clone_S360_ComparisonQuote_Display) :***

```
  <aura:attribute name="Carrier" type="Object[]"/>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <div  class="slds-col">
      <span >
     <p> display comparison carrier:{!v.displayComparison.Carrier__c}"</p>
     <ui:inputSelect aura:id="carrier" value=" 
    {!v.displayComparison.Carrier__c}"  label="Carrier" change=" 
     {!c.CarrierChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Carrier}" var="option">
           <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!option.label}" value=" 
      {!option.value}"    />
        </aura:iteration>
     </ui:inputSelect>
      </span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: is those values are default one for picklist  fields??

Comment: Its not duplicate @glls.Iam facing problem here(please check the image i have attached) ..iam able to pass value from parent to child. Please dont close the question.Iam looking for solution

Comment: looks like its the 3rd time you post this question (you have since deleted the other 2)- havent seen any troubleshooting efforts on your part =( . Are you not able to isolate the issue and describe the problem ? how about you try posting a minimal reproduceable code sample?

Comment: instead of dumping your component code,  check your values on component init, and explain how you are setting those values. try and provide a minimal reproduceable code sample. (learning how to debug your code would also be something you might want to consider)

Comment: even i debugged it..i updated questions as well.. question is iam getting values from parent to child all other value BUT picklist values arenot setting properly. but you already down voted for it. and make it as duplicate also

Comment: No - i retracted my close vote - hoping to see some improvements (same goes with the downvote if post is improved)

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the wrong attributes for the ui:inputSelectOption in the child component. Replace it with below mentioned line

```
<ui:inputSelectOption label="{!option.label}" text="{!option.value}"  value="{!v.displayComparison.Carrier__c == option.value}"><ui:inputSelectOption/>
```